# Custom event table report with custom event parameter in Google Analytics? Is this possible?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm sending the following custom event from my web app.

```
gtag("event", "amazon_click", {
  "event_category": "engagement",
  "event_label": "User clicked on Amazon link",
  "asin": asin
});
```

You can see that I'm adding a custom parameter named `asin`

Will that custom parameter be logged anywhere in Google Analytics? Where can I find it and make a table report that shows this parameter I've added?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an app+web property, you wont be able to use that custom parameter within GA, you would need BigQuery:

> **Custom events** are collected in the same way as automatic and suggested
>   events. However, **since their names are arbitrary and not recognized by
>   App + Web property reports, custom events must instead be analyzed via
>   BigQuery.**
>   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web/tag-guide#custom_events

If you are using a web property, I would instead suggest using custom dimensions and sending the value along with the event.